# emacs hyper key as modifier for windmove

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Have been using **wind-move** package for switching the point b/w windows. The one problem with the **windmove-default-keybindings** function is that the shift is used as the modifier and the **org-mode** grabs the shift-left,right,up,down keys. How to set the **Hyper** key(windows-logo key) as the **modifier**. The below code is used by the windmove package to set the default bindings.

```
(defun windmove-default-keybindings (&optional modifier)
  "Set up keybindings for `windmove'.
Keybindings are of the form MODIFIER-{left,right,up,down}.
Default MODIFIER is 'shift."
  (interactive)
  (unless modifier (setq modifier 'shift))
  (global-set-key (vector (list modifier 'left))  'windmove-left)
  (global-set-key (vector (list modifier 'right)) 'windmove-right)
  (global-set-key (vector (list modifier 'up))    'windmove-up)
  (global-set-key (vector (list modifier 'down))  'windmove-down))
```

Comment: Here is a link to write-up by Xah Lee on this related issue:  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the function, you can pass a modifier name to `windmove-default-keybindings`. In this case:

```
(windmove-default-keybindings 'hyper)
```

You can confirm that this works by using:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd><up>/<down>/<left>/<right></kbd>

And if your hyper modifier is working, then of course you can use:

<kbd><H-up></kbd> / <kbd><H-down></kbd> / <kbd><H-left></kbd> / <kbd><H-right></kbd>

(or you can just bind those directly, similarly to lawlist's answer; windmove just provides the function argument as a convenience)

Answer (score 1):

Solution tested on Windows XP Professional (Service Pack 3) through Parallels Desktop (build 6.0.12090) on OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.8 -- using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN.

```
(setq w32-lwindow-modifier 'super)

(setq w32-rwindow-modifier 'super)

(global-set-key (kbd "<s-up>") 'windmove-up)

(global-set-key (kbd "<s-down>") 'windmove-down)

(global-set-key (kbd "<s-left>") 'windmove-left)

(global-set-key (kbd "<s-right>") 'windmove-right)
```

Comment: On my Windows box (running Windows 7) this doesn't work. Even if I add `(setq w32-pass-lwindow-to-system nil w32-pass-rwindow-to-system nil)`, Windows still captures these (amongst others, like `s-e` and `s-l`).

Comment: I only tested it on Windows XP Professional (Service Pack 3) through Parallels Desktop (build 6.0.12090) on OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.8 -- I verified it works under that circumstance running GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN.

Comment: I think the OP ask for `hyper`, which is `?\H`, not `?\s`.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for helping me to better understand the circumstances where `hyper` may be used.